# apple .replace() Html element generate by handlebar js

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am wondering if how am i able to change the element data by `.replace()` if i use handlebar js to generate html elements.

For instance i have this role of p tag which display a row of data by handlebar js:

```
<p id="pre-region">{{region}}</p>
```

and the result of it is

> 1,44

and i 'd like to change it to

> 1+44

If you haven't had any experience of handlebar js then consider the tag be

```
 <p id="pre-region">1,44</p>
```

how should i change from 1,44 to 1 +44?

**UPDATE 1**

Here should be an extersion for my question. I am passing the HTML element inside pre-region into an href in order to update my website by Ajax.

After i have converted all the comma in to "+" the API retrieve special character "&B2" which equal to the symbol "+" and the API goes error.

> MYDOMAIN/path/getRegion?token&profileId=111&dataType=all&region=1%2B4

This is how may API looks like at the moment

> MYDOMAIN/path/getRegion?token&profileId=111&dataType=all&region=1+4

should be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had any experience of handlebars.js but from my point of view, you can just put the code just before the `</body>`:

```
<script>
  var node = document.getElementById('pre-region');
  node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(',', '+');
</script>
```

I'll check out the handlebars js in case it does not work.

**Update:**
As you mentioned in the comment, if you need to use it in the HTTP request/URL, you may handle the string using `decodeURIComponent(yourstring)`:

```
decodeURIComponent('1%2B44'); // you get '1+44'
```

Read more about `decodeURIComponent()` method from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). In URL, it should be encoded as `region=1%2B44` in your case; while it should be decoded if you want to use it in your JavaScript code or display in the web page.

**Update 1**

You should encode your string when it's used as a part of parameter of HTTP request. Therefore, it looks good if the URL is:

> MYDOMAIN/path/getRegion?token&profileId=111&dataType=all&region=1%2B4

What you need to do is decode the string **on your server side**. I assume that you are in control of the server side. If you are using Node.js, you can just use `decodeURIComponent()` method to decode the parameter. If you're using Python or PHP as your server language, it should be something like `decodeURIComponent()` in that language.

**Update 2**

The solution above only replace the first occasion of comma to `+`. To solve that, simply use:

```
<script>
  var node = document.getElementById('pre-region');
  node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '+'); 
  // Regular Expression is used here, 'g' for global search. 
</script>
```

PHP has a `replaceAll()` method, so we can add that method to `String.prototype` like below if you want:

```
<script>
  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
  }
  // Another method to replace all occasions using `split` and `join`. 
</script>
```

Comment: I tried you method, it changed it to + but alter to special character when passed to the API

Comment: Became something like region=1%2B4

Comment: &region=1%2B4    should be &region=1+44"

Comment: i am not so sure where should i insert "decodeURIComponent()"

Comment: @anson920520 Show me more code and try to describe what you need.

Comment: @anson920520 Check out the update. If you still have any question, shall we move to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110584/discussion-between-iplus26-and-anson920520).

Comment: sorry,i just found that, this only replace the first comma to +. When i tried to input multple number it looks like 1+44,3,56

Comment: @anson920520 Hi I was not sure only one or more occasions. I will update the answer.

Comment: no it's ok  ,i just use regex---- node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '+'); is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so this is my first answer ever on stack overflow so I'm alien to this whole thing but here we go:

You could try this code in another js file that runs after handlebars:

```
var pre = $('#pre-region'); // defines a variabe for the element (same as
                            // document.getElementById('pre-region'))
var retrievedRegion = pre.innerHTML;
var splitten = retrievedRegion.split(',');
var concatenated = parseInt(split[0]) + parseInt(split[1])
retrievedRegion.innerHTML = "'" + concatenated) + "'";
```

or using replace():

```
retrievedRegion.replace(',','+')
```